# Mysql Query for Aging Report

Tags: mysql

I want to create a current,30, 60, 90, day aging reports in Matrix Format using mysql query

For example,

ClientName     Current        1-30         31-60        >90      **Total**

AAA                                                      3000       1500                                                    **4500**

BBB                                                      2000       200               **2200** 

**TOTAL**
                           **3000 3500      200   6700**

i want to get the report like this. when user enters the date, it should check with duedate. when entered date is > due_date, get the aging days.

if aging agin days is today then get netAnmount and display in current column,

if difference is 1-30 days then next column...etc...

how to get query for this?

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    -- ...some stuff ...
    client_id ...,
    due_date date ,
    amount_due ...,
    -- ... some more stuff ...
)
```

Try this:

```
SELECT client_id,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) AS days_past_due,
    SUM(IF(days_past_due = 0, amount_due, 0)),
    SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 1 AND 30, amount_due, 0)),
    SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 31 AND 60, amount_due, 0)),
    SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 61 AND 90, amount_due, 0)),
    SUM(IF(days_past_due > 90, amount_due, 0))
FROM invoices
GROUP BY client_id
```

Comment: Hi john,

i used the above query. 

CurrentDate  is 08-05-2009
DueDate is 2009-06-08

But date difference is displays as 100. 

i have to change the format of date?

pls clarify?

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Comment: OOPS! Indeed, the subtraction doesn't work past month boundaries. I will fix the query in the answer.

Comment: Hi john, i have changed format of currentDate as yyyy-MM-dd. now it is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got Unknown column 'days_past_due' in 'field list' error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments (**Unknown column 'days_past_due'** error) this will work:

```
SELECT client_id, 
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) <= 0, amount_due, 0)) AS current,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 30, amount_due, 0)) AS days30,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) BETWEEN 31 AND 60, amount_due, 0)) AS days60,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) BETWEEN 61 AND 90, amount_due, 0)) AS days90,
    SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), due_date) > 90, amount_due, 0)) AS days90plus
FROM invoices
GROUP BY client_id
```